# UITabBarController viewDidLoad not running

Tags: swift

I have a custom class like below connected to Tab View Controller on storyboard but the problem is the class' viewDidLoad and the didSelected is never called, yet the when i run the app the tab is visible and working fine

```
import UIKit
import Locksmith

class TabViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ANY")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension TabViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate{
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print(item.tag)
        if item == (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[2]{
            let user_id_dict = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: "USER_ID")
            let user_id = user_id_dict?["userId"]
            print("HELLLPP", user_id)
        }
    }
}
```

And in IB its already connected but not running
[image]

Any help please as to why the viewDidLoas and didSelect is never called

Comment: added it as class name in IB ???

Comment: I added it there

Comment: How do you set this vc as a root ?